# docker alpine: autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I have docker alpine image for my project and I need to install `gifsicle` node package, but while installing it I'm getting error

```
Directory: /var/www/abboom-landing/node_modules/gifsicle
Output:
⚠ Response code 404 (Not Found)
  ⚠ gifsicle pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -ivf
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal  --output=aclocal.m4t
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

I found that I need to add `autoconf` and `libtool` packages to my Dockerfile, I did it but still have the same error, and I can't find any valuable solution.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

ENV BUILD_DEPS autoconf file gcc libc-dev make g++ pkgconf re2c git

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $BUILD_DEPS
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .php-build-deps \
        libsodium \
        freetype-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        postgresql-dev  \
        libxml2-dev  \
        libzip-dev \
        libcurl \
        libpng-dev \
        autoconf \
        libtool \
        nasm \
        zlib-dev cyrus-sasl-dev libmemcached-dev

RUN NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1)
## Installable modules
RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv bcmath pdo_mysql opcache pgsql pdo_pgsql soap pcntl exif zip gd calendar dom json
## just good to have installed
RUN apk add --no-cache  ca-certificates wget

RUN  cd ~ \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer


## Install dependencies like editor xdebug etc.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache vim g++ make zlib-dev \
        $BUILD_DEPS \
        && pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN pecl install mongodb \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN pecl install redis \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apk --update add openssh-client

RUN apk add --update nodejs yarn

## configure xdebug
RUN printf "xdebug.cli_color=1\nxdebug.remote_connect_back=1\nxdebug.remote_autostart=1\nxdebug.remote_enable=1\nxdebug.ide_key=PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

ADD php.pool.conf /usr/local/etc
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/


WORKDIR /var/www/

#EXPOSE 22

CMD ["php-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf"]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is missing `aclocal`. It is part of `automake` tools set.

Adding `automake` to dependencies installation should solve this problem.